# should i have multiple custom repository of single entity in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

With lock PESSIMISTIC lock

```java
@Repository
public interface OfferConfigRepoPessimistic extends JpaRepository<OfferConfig, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<OfferConfig> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  Optional<OfferConfig> findOne(Specification specification);
}
```

Without lock PESSIMISTIC lock

```java
@Repository
public interface OfferConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<OfferConfig, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<OfferConfig> {
  Optional<OfferConfig> findOne(Specification specification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how important you think it is to let the consumers of the Repository (or Repositories) know that a Pessimistic Lock is in use for a given query.

In my opinion, I would hide that complexity from the consumers and thus use a single Repository, but others may think differently. Bottom line, I would say this is an opinion-based decision.

Comment: i want to use same query in one business requirement with pesimistic lock and in other requirement without lock . is there any way to achieve this .

Comment: Given that the query is exactly the same, you have no option other than having 2 Repositories.